Attack Action: Can you equip or unequip more than one weapon using the Extra Attack feature or free object interaction?

Can a character with the Extra Attack feature, when taking the Attack action, equip or unequip a weapon twice?

Can a character with the Extra Attack feature, when taking the Attack action and using their "one free interaction per turn", equip or unequip a weapon three times?


The related rules are below.


Attack [Action]
When you take the Attack action, you can make
one attack roll with a weapon or an Unarmed Strike.
Equipping and Unequipping Weapons. You can either equip or unequip one
weapon when you make an attack as part of this action. You do so
either before or after the attack. If you equip a weapon before an
attack, you don’t need to use it for that attack. Equipping a weapon
includes drawing it from a sheath or picking it up. Unequipping a
weapon includes sheathing, stowing, or dropping it.


Time-Limited Object Interactions
When time is short, such as in combat, interactions with objects are
limited: one free interaction per turn. That interaction must occur
during a creature’s movement or action. Any additional interactions
require the Utilize action, as explained in “Combat” later in this
chapter.


Yes to both
The "Equipping and Unequipping Weapons" rule is clear, each attack, not the Attack action, but the actual attack itself, comes with a free equip or unequip.
The general free interaction described under "Time-Limited Object Interactions" is entirely separate; it's a free interaction unrelated to your regular action or bonus action, so you can perform it regardless of what you do with your regular action.
As an example, if you were currently wielding a longsword and shield, and had Extra Attack, it would be completely legal to:

Attack a neighboring enemy with the longsword, then sheathe the longsword as that attack finishes (for free, as part of the attack)
Draw a dagger (for free, as part of the upcoming attack) and throw it at an enemy
Use your free object interaction (not part of the Attack action) to draw the longsword again, leaving you in the same state you began the round in (except one of your daggers has been thrown at an enemy)

And if you pick up the Dual Wielder feat, it comes with:

Quick Draw. You can draw or stow two weapons that lack the Two-Handed property when you would normally be able to draw or stow only one.

and now you could double the number of weapon manipulations per round (including the one for the free object interaction), and just look like the world's weirdest blender, swords just drawing or sheathing every second (six times per six second round), cause why not?

Thanks for the answer! I have a question related to your response. When you say, "you could redraw your other shortsword as part of the action attacking with your already equipped off-hand shortsword", is that redraw part of the Bonus Action attack? I recently asked about this here and in my opinion is not allowed.

@Tarod: Oops, I misread those rules. On rechecking, yeah, bonus actions aren't legal for it. I've removed those claims from the answer.

Quick Draw doesn't let you draw/stow six times per round. You can still only do it three times, but can do it with two weapons at a time.

@Adeptus: I consider that a distinction without a difference in 99.9% of cases, but sure. Six weapons are drawn or stowed, which still works out to one draw or stow per second, which is the important/ridiculous thing.

-----UPDATE/EDIT-----
I believe the answer is no because of the way the Thrown weapon property is written (emphasis mine).

If a weapon has the Thrown property, you can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack, and you can draw that weapon as part of the attack.

If the general rule was for any weapon to be drawn-able per attack, then the thrown weapon rule would not have to have this clause added to it. Because it is added though, then this is a specific rule that overrides the general rule of only one free object interaction per action (which includes equipping/unequipping).
So to answer the posted question:

Can a character with the Extra Attack feature, when taking the Attack action, equip or unequip a weapon twice?

No, only one free object interaction per action as defined by the Interacting with Things rule and inferred from the Thrown weapon rule.

Can a character with the Extra Attack feature, when taking the Attack action and using their "one free interaction per turn", equip or unequip a weapon three times?

No, because the one free object interaction includes drawing/sheathing, as defined by the Utilize action.
-----ORIGINAL RESPONSE BELOW BREAK-----

The rules can be interpreted in both ways. This is an alternative answer to ShadowRanger's answer.
The Utilize action says:

You normally interact with an object while doing something else, such as when you draw a sword as part of the Attack action.

This definiton limits one interaction per Attack action.
In the Combat chapter, it says:

Interacting with Things. You can interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe.

This definiton limits one interaction per general Action or a move.
The Rules Glossary says a weapon is an object:

A weapon is an object that is in the Simple or Martial weapon category.

So when the rules tall about equipping and unequipping weapons, it could be interpreted as one weapon per action, regardless of the number of attacks.

You can either equip or unequip one weapon when you make an attack as part of this action. [Emphasis mine.]

I don't think ShadowRanger's answer is necessarily wrong, I just don't think the rules are written clearly one way or the other as I can see how the other way can be interpreted.

I'm not convinced by this answer. Specific beats general, and the text in "Equipping and Unequipping Weapons" is definitely more specific than the one from the Utilize action. I also don't see how the text could be interpreted as "one weapon per Attack action" when the interaction is directly linked to "an attack", and not "an action". But maybe my non-native english is to blame for that second part, and this is indeed a valid interpretation of the sentence.

@Matthieu: It's the less intuitive interpretation in my mind (as a native English speaker), but it's a possible one. English just isn't that precise. I've tried to think of wholly unambiguous phrasings that would indicate it's definitely one free equip/unequip for each attack in the Attack action, and it's surprisingly difficult to come up with one that is concise, reads naturally for an action defined in terms of a single attack (even though most weapon-focused classes end up with two-plus attacks eventually), and doesn't read like it came from a law book.

@ShadowRanger updated my answer
